# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'ssh2_exec' (T_STRING)

Tags: php, ssh2-exec

I want to dump mysql database with ssh connection.

```
<?php
$vps_ip= 'xxxxxx';
$user="yyyy";
$passwd="zzzz";
$connection = ssh2_connect($vps_ip, 22);
ssh2_auth_password($connection, $user,$passwd);
$cmd="mysqldump -u root -pmypass database > /home/back.sql"
ssh2_exec($connection,$cmd);
?>
```

The error message:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'ssh2_exec' (T_STRING) in  **** on line 7
```

I can dump mysql database into /home/back.sql

```
mysqldump -u root -pmypass database > /home/back.sql
```

How to fix the parser error in 'ssh2_exec'?

Comment: off-topic, missing semi-colon in `$cmd="mysqldump -u root -pmypass database > /home/back.sql"` - you can delete your question

Comment: You are missing a semi-colon on the last but one line that starts `$cmd=`, and as @Fred says, syntax errors are off topic.

Comment: I think there is a special character in mypass. Try $cmd='mysqldump -u root -pmypass database > /home/back.sql' . ie use  single quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$vps_ip= 'xxxxxx';
$user="yyyy";
$passwd="zzzz";
$connection = ssh2_connect($vps_ip, 22);
ssh2_auth_password($connection, $user,$passwd);
$cmd="mysqldump -u root -pmypass database > /home/back.sql" ; //ERROR IS HERE, MISSING ;
ssh2_exec($connection,$cmd);
```

Comment: Don't you ever sleep ? :))) , It's such a small error that I don't think it needs further explanation than a comment in the code.

Comment: hot weather , i fall asleep.